# Android: External Library and JAR Issue

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I made an android calculator in Eclipse.

And in my program, I imported `folder1name.folder2name.file1name` and `folder1name.folder2name.file2name`.

I also added the external library(folder1/folder2/) which contains the JAVA Files(file2, file1) and the JAR Files required for the class which I imported.

But, when I try to run it on the Emulator, it gives an error in the LogCat.

I think it's a problem with the way I added the libs and JARs.

It shows no error with the code.

Please help me fix this error!
I use Eclipse Luna.

Edit: Here're the last 2 lines (red lines) of output.

```
[2014-07-25 09:23:00 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/junit/AggregateTransformer$Format;
[2014-07-25 09:23:00 - OwnCode] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define             Lorg/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/junit/AggregateTransformer$Format;
```

Comment: Yes, please add the logcat

Comment: Letting us see the actual error in your Logcat output is pretty important, yeah.

Comment: Sorry! The error is shown in the console, not the LogCat. I have provided the console error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-
Select project, right click Build Path->Configure Build Path->Order and Export->uncheck the .jar files